# How to format a string using append.text concatenation?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, trackbar

I am using a trackbar to adjust the value accordingly and the output is shown in a text box. I want to show the value with some text after it. The code I have used shows the text I want displayed however also shows this; i.e. slider moved to 200.

i.e. `windowsforms.textbox.text: 200 °C`

```cs
private void trackBar_Temp_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Oven_Temp.Text = trackBar_Temp.Value.ToString();
    Oven_Temp.AppendText(Oven_Temp + "°C");
}
```

How comes the code shows the windows form section in the output with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to append the text should just be: `Oven_Temp.AppendText("°C");`

Better yet, use string concatenation to just do it all in one line:
`Oven_Temp.Text = trackBar_Temp.Value.ToString() + "°C";`

The problem is that you are including `Oven_Temp` inside your call to `AppendText`, which is the textbox object itself. So the type name of the textbox then shows up in your output.